# Firebase cloud function make a database query

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to create a Firebase cloud function that calculates an average from a node's property.

This is the structure of my Real Time Database

```
-- Buildings
  - BuildingID1
    - finalResult: 6.5
    - Reviews
      -ReviewID1
         - rate : 10
      -ReviewID2 
         - rate : 3
- BuildingID
    - finalResult: 1.5
    - Reviews
      -ReviewID
         - rate : 2
      -ReviewID 
         - rate : 1
```

In order to do so, everytime a child node (i.e. a Review) is added/removed/updated.I want to check the rate property and sum it with the rest of other Reviews' grade property, then divide the result by the number of nodes.
...the final result will be displayed in a new property called finalResult.

This is my function so far, but I'm struggling to find a way of querying the database in order to grab the grade property from the other nodes. Could you please help me?

```
export const schoolUpdated = functions.database.ref('/buildings/{buildingId}/reviews/{buildingId}/rate').onWrite( (change, context) => {

  const data = change.after.val();

 // ** calculate the result by querying the the reviews **/

return change.after.ref.parent.parent.parent.child('finalResult').set(result);

});
```

Comment: I think you'll be better off if you keep both a running count and and average for each building.  When a new review is added, you can fetch just those two numbers, then write back to those running values: `average=(average*count+rating)/(count+1)` and `count=count+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the following function and let me know:

```
export const schoolUpdated = functions.database.ref('/buildings/{buildingId}/reviews/{buildingId}/rate').onWrite( (change, context) => {
    return Promise.all([admin.database().ref(`/buildings/${context.params.buildingId}/reviews`).once('value')]).then(r => {
      const allReviews = r[0];
      let sumScore = 0;
      let count = 0;
      allReviews.forEach(item => {
        sumScore += item.child('rate').val();
        count = count + 1;
      });
      let result = (sumScore / count);
      return change.after.ref.parent.parent.parent.child('finalResult').set(result);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer clicking the tilde :)